# Numpy: average over one dimension in "jagged" 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jagged-arrays, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have an N*M*X-dimensional array "data", where N and M are fixed, but X is variable for each entry data[n][m].

(Edit: To clarify, I just used np.array() on the 3D python list which I used for reading in the data, so the numpy array is of dimensions N*M and its entries are variable-length lists)

I'd now like to compute the average over the X-dimension, so that I'm left with an N*M-dimensional array. Using np.average/mean with the axis-argument doesn't work, so the way I'm doing it right now is just iterating over N and M and appending the manually computed average to a new list, but that just doesn't feel very "python":

```
avgData=[]
for n in data:
    temp=[]
    for m in n:
        temp.append(np.average(m))
    avgData.append(temp)
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I'm trying to freshen up my python skills while I'm at it, so interesting/varied responses are more than welcome! :)

Thanks!

Comment: How is the data stored?  numpy doesn't provide any way to do jagged arrays (`X` is always a constant as far as numpy is concerned), so you must be filling those values with *something* or using a masked array or ...

Comment: @mgilson Edited the question. I just had a 3D python list and called np.array() on it. So I guess it's a 2D array of list objects?

Comment: If you don't know how the data is layed out, how should we? You can use the `.shape` and `.dtype` attributes of your array to check this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

```
do_avg = np.vectorize(np.average)
data_2d = do_avg(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = np.array([[1,2,3],[0,3,2,4],[0,2],[1]]).reshape(2,2)
avg=np.zeros(data.shape)
avg.flat=[np.average(x) for x in data.flat]
print avg
#array([[ 2.  ,  2.25],
#       [ 1.  ,  1.  ]])
```

This still iterates over the elements of data (nothing un-Pythonic about that).  But since there's nothing special about the `shape` or `axes` of `data`, I'm just using `data.flat`.  While appending to Python `list`, with `numpy` it is better to assign values to the elements of an existing array.

There are fast numeric methods to work with numpy arrays, but most (if not all) work with simple numeric `dtypes`.  Here the array elements are `object` (either list or array), numpy has to resort to the usual Python iteration and list operations.

For this small example, this solution is a bit faster than Zwicker's `vectorize`.  For larger `data` the two solutions take about the same time.

Comment: Interesting! I considered using reshape, but didn't quite know how. And I didn't mean iterating over elements wasn't un-pythonic, just that there would be a solution that reads a bit cleaner than using for-loops..

Comment: One or the other there's going to be a loop, whether it is in a compiled function, hidden in a Python function, or explicit.  If the 3rd dimension wasn't jagged, it would be a true 3d array, and you could simply average on that 3rd dim.  I should dig into `vectorize` to see what it does to hide the loop.