# Sum of column if not a square matirx in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, jupyter-notebook

```
a=np.array([[1,2,3],[1]])
print(np.sum(a,axis=1))
```

I am assuming that a matrix will be like

```
[1,2,3]
[1]
```

Comment: And what's exactly your question?

Comment: linked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20572316/numpy-average-over-one-dimension-in-jagged-3d-array

Answer (score 0):

Not very general, because it only works if the first line is the longest, but you can simply stick your array into an array of zeros.
For example:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5]])

dim_x = len(a[0])
dim_y = a.shape[0]

a0 = np.zeros((dim_y, dim_x))

for i in range(dim_y):
    dim = len(a[i])
    a0[i,0:dim] = a[i]
```